# Recruitment agencies on careers

Tags: support, jobs, recruitment

I just got a message from a recruitment agent on careers - I was under the impression that careers was for actual employers and not for recruitment agencies.

Has this changed?

Comment: But... `Job Con Sulting` was his actual name! Honestly!

Comment: @TheP.G.RepMiningCo. - I should have seen the "Con" in that name and figured it out!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yup... That's a recruiting agency alright... Not quite playing by the rules. We do allow access to recruiters if and only if they are recruiting for a specific position at a specific client and they disclose this (i.e. the client effectively outsourced their recruiting to the agency).

It looks like that restriction didn't make it all the way across. We'll reach out to them and reiterate our policy and will keep a close eye on this.

Comment: The way the message was phrased is part of the problem. It has no mention of a specific job - "I am keen to have a chat" just sounds like someone trying to get my details on file.

Comment: I've had a couple or so messages from some recruiting agencies.  Although they did disclose that information rather clearly, I didn't know it was actually not allowed for them to exist.  You might want to check those who have contacted me if you're cleaning house.

Comment: @JeffMercado - What Korneel is saying is that they _are_ allowed, so long as they recruit for a specific position on behalf of a company. If that is not the case (it wasn't clear they had a specific position or there was no specific position), then they are not playing by the rules.

Comment: How can I get your attention about one that hasn't disclosed any information ("reply to me get to get the job spec")? Seems a bit futile to me, as my email is fairly visible to Google, but obviously he believes there's a point to it.

Comment: @ChrisS Sorry for slow reply... Please email details to careers at stackoverflow dot com. We'll reach out to them to make sure they will stop doing that.